# Are there any type 2 JDBC drivers to communicate with SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, driver, jtds

Recently we tried [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and Microsoft JDBC driver 4.0 to evaluate the performance of our application which data is stored in SQL Server 2012. According to the benchmark result, Microsoft JDBC driver 4.0 is slightly better than jTDS.

Our senior technical director shared his experience with us that he tried using type 2 native API driver to exchange data between applications and **Oracle database** to boost the performance several years ago. But after hours of searching, we could not find any type 2 JDBC driver for SQL Server.

So we'd like to know are there any type 2 JDBC drivers available to communicate with SQL Server? Thanks very much.

Note : We tried jTDS version 1.2.8 instead of the latest version because we developing applications with JDK 1.6 currently.

Comment: I would prefer type-4 drivers to all other driver types. They are (in my experience) always faster. JNI is notoriously slow in Java, and type-2 drivers are written against JNI. Finally, they're a hack for databases that don't have pure Java drivers.

Comment: I highly doubt that a type 2 driver will change anything. Plus I don't believe your "senior technical director". The Type 2 driver _might_ have been faster 10 years ago with JDK 1.2 or JDK 1.3. But Oracle has been recommending the thin driver ("aka type 4") for several years now amongst other reasons "to get the best performance". Do you actually _have_ a performance problem that is directly related to the data transfer?